# Prove that $AA^+x=x$ for $\forall x \in range(A)$

Tags: matrices, pseudoinverse

How can I prove that $AA^+x=x$ for any vector $x \in range(A)$, where $A$ is a non-zero matrix?

Comment: Is $A^+$ the pseudo inverse?

Comment: Stack exchange is not meant as a replacement of textbooks, I believe. It _is_ more amenable to copy/paste than printed textbooks, I'll admit.

Comment: @CameronWilliams yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x \in range(A)$, $x=Ay$ for some $y$.

$$AA^+x=AA^+Ay=Ay=x$$

since $AA^+A=A.$